# Using doc2vec embeddings as model input our perhaps similarity comparison?

Tags: natural-language, word2vec, doc2vec

Doc2vec is an extension of word2vec, which creates vector representations of documents.

One can use this representations as input to some classifier/regression(Logistic Regression, XGboost, LightGBM ...).

What about using the similarity as a prediction. Let's say you define some typical examples of classes through clustering or by choice and than you similarity to these examples as a prediction.

Is that a decent plan? Is it something that is used with doc2vec/word2vec.